# Cannot escape double quotes and slashes when initializing an input in html

Tags: html, parsing, escaping

I have an input text field in HTML. 
I want to put the value `reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command"`
into the input field when my page loads.

If I do `<input readonly="readonly" type='text' id="john" value="reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command"">` 
Then the input field dispays

> reg query

Then I tried escaping using a backslash for every double quote and slash like so,

```
<input readonly="readonly" type='text' id="john" value="reg query \"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\mailto\\shell\\open\\command\"">
```

The result I get is not at all satisfactory

> reg query \

I managed to find a workaround which is rather too much I feel . the work-around is

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Issues with values</title>

 <script>
  function show()
  {
  document.getElementById('john').value = "reg query \"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\mailto\\shell\\open\\command\"";
  }
</script>

<body>
text :  <input readonly="readonly" type='text' id="john" value="reg query \"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\mailto\\shell\\open\\command\""> 
    <button id='1' onClick="show()">Start time</button>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the button I get the desired output

> reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command"

**Question is how to put/parse/escape that value inside the input value as a default???**

Comment: `<input readonly="readonly" type='text' id="john" value='reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command"'>` also works, just tested on Firefox

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre...worked like a charm, y didnt I think of that

Comment: no problem, I did not think it would work either but it did :)